# How to install "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" assembly?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-assembly, iis-8, codedom

How to install "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" assembly on a computer without Visual Studio? But it has .NET framework, ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime and IIS Express 8.0.

Comment: What do you mean by "install"? Do you want to add it to GAC? Or just use it in an application?

Comment: Use it in an application. It works on other Windows. But it does not work in Windows 2008. In Windows 2008 ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime is not installing "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" assembly.

Comment: How does it not work? What error are you getting? I think that assembly is normally copied with your application, on any OS.

Comment: In Windows 2008, it is not installing correctly. That is why I asked please.